# Definitions of inner and outer regular measures

Tags: measure-theory

The definitions can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure#Definition).

I am trying to figure out why it's defined specifically this way. More precisely- Why compact sets are used to define inner regularity while open sets are used for outer regularity?

I thought that maybe it has something to do with the facts that the union of open sets is open and that (in a Hausdorff space) the intersection of compact sets is compact, but I dont see how these matter.
Another thought I had is that maybe the motive comes from Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Terminology differs among authors. Another def'n is that a measure $m$ is Radon-regular iff each measurable set $S$ satisfies $m(S)=\sup \{m(T):S\supset T \land T$ compact $\},$ and that inner-regular means $m(S)=\sup \{m(U):S\supset U=\bar U\}.$ In many cases, Radon-regular and inner-measure co-incide.

The motivation is that we can say much more about regular measures because regularity is a relation between the measure  and the topology of the measure space.

For example a set $S$ is Lebesgue-measurable iff there exists a $G_{\delta}$ set $ S^i$ and an $F_{\sigma}$ set $S^o$ with $S^i\subset S \subset S^o$ and $m^o (S^o$  \ $S^i)=0.$

One of the motives of Lebesgue measure was attempts to extend calculus to  a much broader class of functions,  which resulted in extending the notion of length or volume. ...Note the outer measure involves  intersections of subsets of a (usually infinite ) family of open sets, and the inner measure involves  unions of closed sets.

Comment: "One of the motives of Lebesgue measure was attempts to extend calculus to a much broader class of functions..." Did it work?

Comment: @goblin. Yes.....................

Comment: @DanielWainfleet What would be an example of a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $m^*(E)= \sup_{U\subset E,U open} m^*(U)$ is not true, $m^*$ is outer measure.

Comment: @goal. Let $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$  Let $F_n=(q_n-2^{-n},\,q_n+2^{-n}).$ Let $E=\Bbb R\setminus \cup_{n\in \Bbb N}F_n.$ If $U$ is open and non-empty then $U$ contains a member of $\Bbb Q$ so $U\not\subset E.$

Comment: Why use compact sets and not closed sets?